# When does the .NET FormAuthentication ticket get checked and how do I tap into this event?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

We are attempting to integrate an ASP.NET MVC site with our client's SSO system using PingFederate. I would like to use the built in FormsAuthentication framework to do this. The way I've gone about it so far is:

1. Set up my Web.config so that my FormsAuthentication LoginURL goes to my site's "BeginAuthentication" action on a "Security" controller. From this action, I set up some session variables (what URL was being accessed, for example, since Ping won't send this info back to me), and then redirect to our client's login page on an external site (www.client.com/Login for example).
2. From here, the authentication takes place and a cookie is generated on the same domain as the one that our application is running on which contains the unique identifier of the authenticated user, I've set it up so that once this happens, the Ping server will redirect to my "EndAuthentication" action on my "Security" controller.
3. In this action, I call my membership class's "ValidateUser" method which takes this unique identifier from the cookie and loads in the user on our application that this ID refers to. I save that logged in user in our Session (Session["LoggedInAs"], for example) and expire the cookie that contains the id of the authenticated user that the SSO system provided for me.

All of this works well. The issue I'm wondering about is what happens after our user has already authenticated and manually goes back to our client's login page (www.client.com/login) and logs in as another user. If they do that, then the flow from #2 above to number 3 happens as normal - but since there already exists an authenticated user on our site, it seems as though the FormsAuthentication system doesn't bother kicking off anything so I don't get a chance to check for the cookie I'm looking for to login as this new user. What I'd like to do is, somewhere in my Global.asax file (probably FormsAuthenticate_OnAuthenticate), check to see if the cookie that the SSO system sends to me exists, and if so, sign out of the application using FormsAuthentication.SignOut().

Another issue that seems to be related is that if I let my Session expire, the FormsAuthentication still seems to think I am authenticated and it lets me access a page even though no currently logged in user exists in my Session, so the page doesn't render correctly. Should I tap into the Session_End event and do FormsAuthentication.SignOut() here as well?

Basically, I want to know when the authentication ticket created by 
System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(..) gets checked in the flow of a request so that I can determine whether I need to SignOut() and force revalidation or not.

Thanks for any help. Sorry for the length of this message, trying to be as detailed as possible.

Mustafa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the small section of Hades that is mixing session with formsauth.

If your needs are as complex as presented, you would get more sleep if you implement a full provider stack to share amongst the participating sites. Easier said than done, I know.

But to address your question:

from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39026/Exploring-Web-config-system-web-httpModules.aspx

On the way in....Check ticket and set identity @

```
app.AuthenticateRequest += System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule.OnEnter-->OnAuthenticate
```

On the way out... set the ticket and redirect as necessary

```
app.EndRequest += System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule.OnLeave
```

[**Reflector**](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) is your friend. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a specific event for when the cookie is checked, but you could place the appropriate logic in `Application_BeginRequest()` and check the user's authentication state there.

Answer (score 1):

> Another issue that seems to be related
>   is that if I let my Session expire,
>   the FormsAuthentication still seems to
>   think I am authenticated and it lets
>   me access a page even though no
>   currently logged in user exists in my
>   Session, so the page doesn't render
>   correctly.

The life of the cookie (how long until ASP.NET feels it needs to ask for a password again) and how you are managing state are unrelated.  The ASP.NET authentication is cookie based so that, should a developer want to, he could turn off viewstate, session, use no query strings or hidden fields and authentication still works.

If you want to tie the interval at which you request the password to how you are persisting data, then you will want your session expiration to be roughly the same as the cookie expiration, but they will never quite match up.  It would be better to have two policies (one for how fast you throw away a users session data and one for how long you are willing to wait before you need to reask for a password)